# Mathematical operators in SQL not excluding "NA" values

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I am using the code below to switch between searching in a database entries that are above or below an entered value in a certain column.

```
if (isset($_POST["abovebelow"]) && $_POST["abovebelow"] == "Above"){

    $operator = ">";

}

elseif (isset($_POST["abovebelow"]) && $_POST["abovebelow"] == "Below"){

    $operator = "<";

}

elseif (!isset($_POST["abovebelow"])){

    $operator = "LIKE";
    $value = "%";

}

$result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t.column FROM table t WHERE t.value".$operator." ( ? );");

$result->bind_param($value);
$result->execute();
```

For this data set, t.value is either -1,0,1 or NA. When I set the query to above -1 or 0, NA values also show up. But when I set it to below 1 or 0, no NA values show up. Why is this? Is there something I can add to the query to prevent the NA values from showing up when above or below is selected (but not when nothing is selected)?

The way I am thinking about the above question would be: is there a way to have varying amount of parameters in a query? I am thinking if above or below is selected, then the query could be appended with "AND t.value != 'NA'". This would also help to have a check box to allow or not allow "NA" values at the user's discretion with the above/below criteria.

Comment: How are `NA` values stored in MySQL? Is it `NULL`?

Comment: If you just want different queries you could move it inside the if statements.

Comment: NA values are stored as "NA" not null. I can't put it inside the if statements because above is a simplified version. I have multiple operators and values and wouldn't want to write all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the thinking from Jaco's answer, I added

```
$operator = "<> 'NA' and t.value >";
```

to each operator part, instead of adding into query. This gave flexibility for the neither above nor below part to include or not include the 'NA'

Answer (score 3):

You can just add an additional `WHERE` clause to filter these values out. Assuming your NA values are stored as a string (`'NA'`) you can filter them out like this:

```
SELECT t.column FROM table t WHERE t.value<> 'NA' AND t.value".$operator." ( ? );
```

If you want to show up the NA values in the not checked case you can use the following query that ignores the check for `NA` when the operator is set to `LIKE`

```
SELECT t.column FROM table t WHERE (t.value <> 'NA' OR "$operator"="LIKE") AND t.value".$operator." ( ? );
```

EDIT: the second approach doesn't quite work as per Steven comments, see Steven's own answer for the correct way of implementing this.

Comment: The NA values wouldn't show up in the not checked case though :(

Comment: I added a second query that will show up the NA values in the not checked case.  It ignores the check on `NA` if the `$operator` is set to `LIKE`

Comment: this gives " Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object " error on the $result->bind_param($value); part.